# Using a single transaction for multiple method C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

Lets say I got an Insert-button where I got multiple method within it, where they read, insert and update etc in the database. Is it possible to use a single transaction for all these called methods? **Like:**

```
    private void method_A(){/* doing tons of db stuff */}
    private void method_B(){/*...*/}
    private void method_C(){/*...*/}

//etc

       protected void Insert_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
        //begin transaction

        Method_A();

        Method_B();

        Method_C();

        //end transaction


        }
```

Is this way possible? Never used transaction before. 
Btw using MS Access db if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you could use a single transaction by creating an instance of the transaction and passing it into any method that would need to use it. Some psuedo-code to illustrate based on the code you've provided: A link as well: [MSDN OleDbTransaction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93ehy0z8(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
protected void Insert_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       //begin transaction
       var connection = HoweverYoureManagingConnections();
       using (var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())//If using OleDb 
       {

       try
       {
           var command = new OldDbCommand();
           command.Transaction = transaction;
           //Use passed in command object to issue your queries/inserts/updates in each method.
           Method_A(command);

           Method_B(command);

           Method_C(command);

           transaction.Commit();
       }
       catch(Exception ex)
       {
           //if there was an exception rollback.
           transaction.Rollback();
       }
       }


    }
```

Comment: Thanks sorry for late reply, but how do I receive that  `command` argument in methods parameter?

Answer (score 4):

Not certain if Access honors transactions but you can wrap the calls in a `TransactionScope`.  That implicitly adds all database activity within the scope to the transaction:

```
protected void Insert_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(TransactionScope tran = new TransactionScope())
    {
        Method_A();
        Method_B();
        Method_C();

        tran.Complete();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply, how do I use `TransactionScope` in first place? It turns red when I call it on visual studio. I can hardly find any info about that. I tried with `using System.Transactions.TransactionScope;` as well.

Comment: @Nyprez Did you add `Sytste.Transactions` as a reference in your project?  (That's different than just adding `using System.Transactions;`.

Comment: @D Stanley TransactionScope doesn't work with Mc Access. However, thank you for a great example of transaction for using e.g. sql server.